# send request from server to web application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm not sure my title is the good explain of my problem so i will try to explain here.

I have a springBoot application on my server, and using angular for front.

I send a request to my server :

```java
@PostMapping(value="/setup/rate/electricityToImport")
public void updateNewElectricityRate( HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, SAXException, ParseException {
    String rate = request.getParameter("electricityToImport");      

    system.out.println(rate);

    //here i will save rate in file.

}
```

```js
var rate = this.myGridImport.getselectedcell()['value'];
console.log(rate)

$.ajax({
  url: "/api/setup/rate/electricityToImport",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "text",
  data: 'electricityToImport=' + rate
})
```

Now i want to know if the file is saved and display "File Saved" on the front (angular application)
but how can i send to my front that save is finished well

Thanks a lot for your help!
Math

Comment: Are you saying that the file is on the client and you want to send it using a web browser and then save in on a server?

Comment: not exactly, i modify the file which is on my server with my web application, after modify, i send modification to my server which save the news values. After save, i want to tell me to my client that the save of my file is finished well

Comment: You can use ajax onsuccess - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Answer (score 1):

@mavriksc has already shown proper methods. Normally you can achieve that in two ways:

#### shared service

If you are using a shared global service to handle request, you can just handle the response error there (if no error, then you can just tell the clients **saved successfully**, right?).

It could be something like this:

```
getJson(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http
      .get(a_url_here)
      .pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        console.log("Data got: ");
        console.log(res);
        return res;
      }),
      catchError(error => this.handleError<string>(error, "Network Error!"))
    );
  }
```

#### standalone request

If you are requesting in your component directly or handle the error there, you can achieve that along with `subscribe()` as this:

```
this.getYourData(your_url).subscribe(jsonStr => this.testContent = jsonStr, 
                              error => this.handleError<string>(error, "Network Error!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

web frameworks will return an error code if you throw an exception from your controller, otherwise return `200OK` . so in your angular front end your client will have some Observable as a response to this request. in `complete` you can display file saved. and in `error` you can display some info about that.